# My WEBrick server is nerver deleting PID file for a specifc project, what do i do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pid, webrick, server

I searched a lot already and I didn't find anything useful.

Could someone help me.

When WEBrick server is stopped It should delete the server.pid file from tmp folder, but It is never being erased.

I wonder why it is happing, because it just happens with one and only project, the others is ok, if i create a new one it is ok too. What configuration on that project could cause that problem, any clue?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: are you using `ctrl+z` to stop?

Comment: No, I'm using ctrl+c to stop, and even if it was ctrl+z, why the same command on different projects make different results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution...

I had a custom jasper-rails gem into my ruby gems directory with version 0.0.2, when I created this problem project and run bundle install it installed jasper-rails 1.0.3, because I did'nt set the version on Gemfile.

For some reason the jasper-rails gem was causing the problem.

My fix:

Edited Gemfile = gem 'jasper-rails' to gem 'jasper-rails', '0.0.2'
Uninstalled the newer version of jasper-rails: gem uninstall jasper-rails -v 1.0.3